# R - How to remove fixed effects from forest plot

Tags: r, random, fixed, r-forestplot

I am using the forest function from the meta package to plot a forest plot. My code is as follows:

```
forest(meta.MRBL, colgap.forest.left = "3cm", layout = "RevMan5", comb.fixed = FALSE, comb.random = TRUE, xlim = c(0.00,1.00), digits = 3, col.study = "black", col.by = "black")
```

When I run the code, the fixed effects is also appearing (please see image).

How can I remove the fixed effects estimates?
[image: I need the fixed effects removed.]

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting according to a predefined layout (RevMan).
Remove term RevMan and plot using:

```r
forest(meta.MRBL, 
       colgap.forest.left = "3cm", 
       layout = "RevMan5", 
       comb.fixed = FALSE, 
       comb.random = TRUE, 
       xlim = c(0.00,1.00), 
       digits = 3, 
       col.study = "black", 
       col.by = "black",
       common = FALSE).
```

Let me know if this works.